# Is it possible to find Longest common subsequence of all pair of splits of a string in better than $O(n^3)$?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I have  a string $a_0a_1..a_{n-1}$

Lets say we split the string at pos $i$, so the string are

$a_0a_1....a_{i}$ and $a_{i+1}a_{i+2}....a_{n-1}$

Now I need to compute:

$max(LCS(a_0a_1....a_{i} , a_{i+1}a_{i+2}....a_{n-1}))$ for all $i$ in $[0,n-1]$

common LCS algorithms takes $O(n^2)$ time. so if we use that n times it would be $O(n^3)$.
Given that there are many overlapping parts of string can we do better ?

I don't need the subsequence , I just need the max subsequence length and position of splitting.

Comment: You want to find the longest substring of $a_0a_1\cdots a_{n-1}$ that occurs twice in $a_0a_1\cdots a_{n-1}$.  This can be done easily in $O(n^2)$ by finding the longest matching sequence between $a_0a_1\cdots a_{n-1}$ and $a_0a_1 \cdots a_{n-1}$ shifted over by some counter.

Comment: @JosephCamacho subsequence not substring .ie it need not be continuous.

Comment: Equivalently you are finding the longest repeating and non-overlapping substring, cf. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-repeating-and-non-overlapping-substring/

Comment: @VezenBU  subsequence not substring

Comment: substring finding algos like KMP are O(N) but subsequence is $O(N^2)$

Comment: I see, then if I understand it correctly, it is this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35545364/longest-repeated-non-overlapping-subsequence

Comment: @VezenBU Yes. Thanks. Can't find a free source to download the paper  "An Efficient Algorithm for the Longest Tandem Scattered Subsequence Problem" by Adrian Kosowski. Let me know if you can download.It's not on arxiv and I dont have subsription for springer or researchgate. My email is jackernardo55@gmail.com
, do share if you have access